# private static field that is not final?

Tags: java, static, final

Can someone give me an example of when you'd use a `private static` field over a `private static final` field? I struggle to think of an example of when you'd want to declare a `private` class variable, that was subject to change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Enter the Singleton pattern:

```
public class Clazz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObject myObject = MyObject.getInstance();
    }
}

class MyObject {
    private static MyObject instance; 
    //I belong to the class, but I need not be created before somebody wants me.

    private MyObject() {
    }

    public static MyObject getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MyObject();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course! I have even used it myself! I just couldn't remember it!

Comment: It *can* be `final` since it's assigned only once.

Comment: @MarounMaroun What is the preferred way of doing it? final or not?

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

For example when you want to have a counter variable to count how many objects have been created from a class, you'll make it `static` - it's associated with the class and not an object, but it's *not* `final` since it's changing:

```
protected static int counter = 0;

//constructor
counter++;
```

---

Worth mentioning note:

I didn't mention the Singleton example since if you want to be thread-safe, the variable must be `static` and `final`.

Comment: Seems like an obvious use case now that you mention it.

Comment: protected static volatile int counter = 0;

Comment: You can synchronize your initialization block. It is possible to have a thread safe, lazy loading singleton.